# What is wrong with my neural network model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I got a dataset of 178 elements, and each contains 13 features and 1 label.
Label is stored as one-hot array. My training dataset is made of 158 elements.

Here is what my model looks like :

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,training_data.shape[1]])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,training_data_labels.shape[1]])

node_1 = 300
node_2 = 300
node_3 = 300
out_n = 3   

#1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([training_data.shape[1], node_1]))
B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_1]))
y1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),B1)
y1 = tf.nn.relu(y1)

#2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_1, node_2]))
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_2]))
y2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(y1,W2),B2)
y2 = tf.nn.relu(y2)

#3
W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_2, node_3]))
B3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_3]))
y3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(y2,W3),B3)
y3 = tf.nn.relu(y3)

#output
W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_3, out_n]))
B4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([out_n]))
y4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(y3,W4),B4)
y = tf.nn.softmax(y4)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(200):
        sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x:training_data, y_:training_data_labels})

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:eval_data, y_:eval_data_labels}))
```

But the accuracy is very low, i tried increase the range 200 to some higher number but it still remains low.

What could I do to improve the results ?

Comment: The problem is most likely with initialization. Provide your training data to reproduce this

Comment: @Skam it is a homework..

Comment: Why u need argmax method in equal?  I think you should delete both argmax methods, then you might be good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking the softmax of `y4` and then passing that to `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.  This error is common enough that there's actually a note about it in the documentation for [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits):

```
WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally 
for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce 
incorrect results.
```

The rest of your code looks fine, so just replace `y4` with `y` and get rid of `y = tf.nn.softmax(y4)`.